# Python: Decide which scrollbar is moving in ScrolledPanel

Tags: event-handling, wxpython, controls, scrollbar, orientation

This question continue the question on the link : [wxPython Event for ScrolledPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322277/wxpython-event-for-scrolledpanel). I edited the code a little bit so that OnScroll function get the x position of the content's scrollbar and use that to set x position of the header's scrollbar.

My problem is I cannot decide when the horizontal scrollbar is rolled. So my program now has the header's horizontal scrollbar rolled whenever any of the content's scrollbars is rolled while I want the header's h-scrollbar rolled when the content's h-scrollbar is rolled. (Or if anyone can suggest an event triggering by only when scrolling the horizontal bar it will be very good). Thanks ahead.

```
import wx
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel
header = """
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5"""
text =   """
1336        733         1336        4732        1217

5968        4477        1217        5748        4477

1217        5635        4372        1217        5634

4369        1217        5633        4371        217"""

class Test(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(300, 200))
        self.panel=panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vboxA = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.headerPanel = headerPanel = ScrolledPanel(panel, -1, size=(150,32))
        hboxHeader = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.headertc = headertc = wx.TextCtrl(headerPanel, -1, header,
                             size=(500,32),style= wx.TE_READONLY)
        headertc.Unbind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN)

        hboxHeader.Add(headertc,1)
        headerPanel.SetSizer(hboxHeader)
        headerPanel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        headerPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_y = False)
        hbox.Add(headerPanel,1, wx.EXPAND |  wx.ALL,0)

        vboxA.Add(hbox, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        self.textPanel = textPanel = ScrolledPanel(panel, -1, size = (150,150))
        textPanel.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.OnScroll)

        hboxText = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.tc = tc = wx.TextCtrl(textPanel, -1, text, size=(500,500),
                style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_DONTWRAP| wx.TE_READONLY)
        hboxText.Add(tc, 1)
        textPanel.SetSizer(hboxText)
        textPanel.SetAutoLayout(1)
        textPanel.SetupScrolling(scroll_x=True, scroll_y=True)

        vboxA.Add(textPanel,1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL,0)

        vbox.Add(vboxA, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        panel.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)  


    def OnScroll(self, event):
        event.Skip()
        x= event.GetPosition()
        self.headerPanel.Scroll(x,0)
        print event.GetEventType()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1)
    win = Test(frame, "Test scroll bar")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following condition to check for horizontal scrolling in your scroll handler.

```
if event.Orientation == wx.SB_HORIZONTAL:
```